# pandas группировка и срез строк

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
data = {'фрукт': ['груша','груша','арбуз','банан','груша', 'груша', 'вишня', 'груша', 'вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша', 'груша', 'банан'],
'страна': ['россия','сша', np.nan, 'россия', np.nan, np.nan,'канада', 'франция', 'португалия', 'испания', np.nan, np.nan, 'перу'],
'id': ['01','01','01','011', '011', '011', '011', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5', '5'],
'месяц': ['январь','январь','январь','январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'январь', 'март', 'март', 'апрель', 'апрель', 'апрель', 'апрель']        
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно отфильтровать срезы строк с грушей так, чтобы в группе `id` за каждый месяц срез начинался c последней строки, содержащей грушу, и заканчивался строкой, следующей после последней строки с грушей. Обязательное условие - группировка по `id`.

Как можно это сделать?

Ожидаемый результат (также на первом скриншоте выделил, что должны получить в результате):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А строка 8 с вишней, каким образом попала  в желаемый результат?  Она как бы и не с грушей, и начинается не после первой груши  значит не может с нее начинаться отобранное подмножество. Либо - переписывайте по другому условие.

Comment: @passant спасибо, описание поправил, имелась ввиду послднняя запись в группе id со значением фрукта равным груше

Comment: а почему у вас в итоговый датафрейм не вошла груша с индексом 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне не совсем ясно, почему в итог не вошла груша номер 7. Потому что, можно было бы сделать так:

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
for i, g in dates.groupby("id"):
    idx = g.loc[dates["фрукт"]=="груша"].index[-1]
    res = pd.concat([res, dates[idx:idx+2]]).sort_index()
```

тогда `res` будет:

```
   фрукт      страна   id   месяц
1   груша         сша   01  январь
2   арбуз         NaN   01  январь
5   груша         NaN  011  январь
6   вишня      канада  011  январь
7   груша     франция    6    март
8   вишня  португалия    6    март
11  груша         NaN    5  апрель
12  банан        перу    5  апрель
```